# Form with CSS not getting into wrapper div but pops out of it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a website where I got a wrapper div with a:

-Header

-Content

-Footer

Only the problem now is that if I post normal text in the content then it all works and the background also nicely stretches. I also built a form with CSS and if I put this in to the content div then it pops out of the wrapper.

My CSS on my wrapper and content:

```
#wrapper{
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
width:952px;
padding:0 20px 0 21px;
background: green;
position:relative;
}

#content{
  width:898px;
  float:left;
  padding:28px 20px 30px 34px;
  min-height:432px;
  height:auto !important;
  height:432px;
}
```

Please see the example on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1hmkq14v/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `position:absolute;` from `#msform` and `#msform fieldset`

http://jsfiddle.net/1hmkq14v/2/

Comment: yes this is good, there is only still only problem.. there is also a progress bar as you can see with 1,2,3 between that is a line, for example if you remove background:green; from wrapper then you see the line. Do you how i get this line also shown??

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/1hmkq14v/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/1hmkq14v/3/) - added `position:relative;z-index: 2;` for `#progressbar li:before`,  and increased z-index for `#progressbar li:after`

Comment: It works :) on my own website i get this: http://i60.tinypic.com/2aeo5ft.png do you know why this can happen??

Comment: have you added `position:relative;z-index: 2;` for `#progressbar li:before`?

Comment: i forgot position:relative;, is there any site where i can get this knowledge about right positioning ???

Comment: and also why is it so that when i remove:   <br/>
      this must come below the form (see  
http://jsfiddle.net/1hmkq14v/3/) that the green wrapper won't stretch, because there is content??

Comment: add the footer content in a div

Comment: actually i need position:relative in #msform and position:absolute in msform fieldset because i have also a jquery script so that the form will be animated from 1 fieldset to the next.. so are there any other ways????

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86619/discussion-between-bboni-and-afelixj).

Answer (score 1):

add `overflow: auto` to the `wrapper` `div`
fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/1hmkq14v/1/